# Derivatives - three questions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Please check my answer to the following questions:

What is the derivative of:

**1)** $f(t) = e^{2t} \cos(8t)$

Mine answer: $-16e^{2t}\sin(8t)$

**2)** $12 \arctan(x^6)$

Mine answer: $\frac{12}{x^{12}+1}$

**3)** $4\pi^4+ \frac{1}{8t}$

Mine answer: $-\frac{1}{(8t)^2}$

Comment: The last one is almost correct, the first two are not. Do you know the product rule and the chain rule?

Comment: If the matter is just checking answers, you can use this site: http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 4):

1. Use product rule, followed by chain rule (not shown below) where necessary.
   $$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{2t} \cos(8t))=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{2t})\cos (8t)+e^{2t}\frac{d}{dt}(\cos(8t))=\ldots$$
2. Use chain rule as shown below.
   $$\frac{d}{dt}(12 \arctan(x^6))=\frac{12}{1+x^{12}} \frac{d}{dx}(x^6)=\ldots$$
3. No need to add parentheses around the $8t$ in your final step. $$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{8t}=\frac 18 \frac{d}{dt} \frac 1t=\frac 18 \left(-\frac {1}{t^2} \right)=-\frac{1}{8t^2}$$